# Issues sqflite in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

It's been a while I started flutter. And now I am working on the database part. I started with sqflite since it was the ideal one for offline apps but now I can't understand a thing please can somebody help me with this.

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'note.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class DatabaseHelper {
  static DatabaseHelper _databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper();
  static Database? _database;

  String noteTable = 'note_table';
  String colID = 'id';
  String colTitle = 'title';
  String colDescription = 'description';
  String colPriority = 'priority';
  String colDate = 'date';

  DatabaseHelper._createInstance();

  factory DatabaseHelper() {
    if (_databaseHelper == null) {
      var databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper._createInstance();
      _databaseHelper = databaseHelper;
    }
    return _databaseHelper;
  }

//custom getter for the database
  Future<Database> get database async {
    // ignore: prefer_conditional_assignment
    if (_database == null) {
      _database = await initializeDatabase();
    }
    return _database!;
  }

  Future<Database> initializeDatabase() async {
    Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = directory.path + 'note.db';
    var notesDatabase =
        await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _createDb);
    return notesDatabase;
  }

  void _createDb(Database db, int newVersion) async {
    await db.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE $noteTable($colID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, $colTitle TEXT, $colDescription TEXT, $colPriority INTEGER, $colDate TEXT)');
  }

  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getNoteMapList() async {
    Database db = await this.database;
    var result = await db.query(noteTable, orderBy: '$colPriority ASC');
    return result;
  }

  Future<int> insertData(Note note) async {
    Database db = await this.database;
    var result = await db.insert(noteTable, note.toMap());
    return result;
  }

  Future<int> updateNote(Note note) async {
    Database db = await this.database;
    var result = await db
        .update(noteTable, note.toMap(), where: '$colID', whereArgs: [note.id]);
    return result;
  }

  Future<int> deleteNote(int id) async {
    Database db = await this.database;
    var result =
        await db.rawDelete('DELETE FROM $noteTable where $colID = $id');
    return result;
  }

  Future<int> getCount() async {
    Database db = await this.database;
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> x =
        await db.rawQuery('SELECT COUNT (*) FROM $noteTable');
    int? result = Sqflite.firstIntValue(x);
    return result!;
  }

  Future<List<Note>> getNoteList() async {
    var noteMapList = await getNoteMapList();

    int count = noteMapList.length;
  }
}
```

This is the whole code. I have watched many videos but can't understand a thing. The problem starts when I the database part starts. And while answering the questions please try to be a little simple.

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: I think you need to get sql first, also you can try searching how to use `sqflite` or you can read on [doc](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite)

Comment: This not a question I just can't understand this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.